# Dynamic EditText is not adding above specified element in linear layout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add dynamic EditText in linear layout on click of a button.My problem is whenever I click button its is successfully adding EditText field but below the Button I want to show EditText above Button.

My root layout is Linear layout

Below is my code:

**Layout file**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/costLayout"
    android:id="@+id/dynamicLayout">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rulingTypeWrapper"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:hint="Add ruling type"
        android:id="@+id/product_rule_type"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/addField"
        android:text="ADD"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java code**

```
  protected void createEditTextView() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.setMargins(16,10,16,10);
    TextInputEditText edittTxt = new TextInputEditText(this);

    int maxLength = 50;
    hint++;
    edittTxt.setHint("Ruling type");
    edittTxt.setLayoutParams(params);
    edittTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    edittTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18);
    edittTxt.setId(hint);
    InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
    fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
    edittTxt.setFilters(fArray);
    parentLayout.addView(edittTxt);
}
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Please post the code of your root layout.

Comment: I have updated post I want to add fields above button but they are adding below it.

Comment: is the parentLayout referencing the dynamic layout on the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are adding the dynamic edittext on the parent layout which also consists of the button. So, add a linear layout as below above the button and add your dynamic fields to that linear layout. It should solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/costLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rulingTypeWrapper"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:hint="Add ruling type"
            android:id="@+id/product_rule_type"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- moved the dynamic layout id here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/dynamicLayout" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/addField"
        android:text="ADD"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A vertical LinearLayout will order its child Views from top to bottom in the order of how they were added. First child added is placed at the top. Last child is placed at the bottom. You added EditText when button is already added, thus it is placed at the bottom. You could remove the button and add it after the EditText is already added.

A more simple solution would be to just add the EditText in the xml above the button and set `visibility` to `gone`. Then you get the EditText through `findViewById` and then call `editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. After that, you could also set its layout parameters and other properties. This is if the intention is to just add a single EditText. If more than one, then you could try to do what @shr3jn suggested. If even more, then use ListView. If much much even more, then use RecyclerView.